# Invoke-VMScript - How to get the gateway of a VM into a variable?

Tags: powershell, powercli

I'm currently working on scripts which will be used to automate the process of VM creation on VMWare  using templates and a CSV.

After changing the network parameters of the VM, I would like to compare my CSV to the network configuration of the VM, to confirm that it match.

The comparison work with the IP but not with the Gateway.

I don't manage to make it work. Could you help me ?

Part of the script:

```
$vm= import-csv C:\temp\create_vm.csv -Delimiter ';'

foreach($vms in $vm){

 $ipmodif = "New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex 12 -ipaddress $($vms.ip) -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $($vms.gateway)" 

   [void](Invoke-VMScript -VM $vms.machine -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText $ipmodif -GuestUser Administrator -GuestPassword password)


   Write-host "INSTALLATION DE $($vms.machine)..." -ForegroundColor Yellow


 $ipget= Get-VM -name $vms.machine | Select @{N="IP";E={@($_.guest.IPAddress[0])}}

 $gateway = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | select-object DefaultIPGateway

 $gatewayget = Invoke-VMScript -VM $vms.machine -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText "$($gateway)"  -GuestUser Administrator -GuestPassword Password

   if ($vms.ip -eq $ipget.ip){Write-host  "Adresse IP ($($vms.ip))      : " -NoNewline
                              Write-host "OK" -foreground green}

        else {Write-host  "Adresse IP ($($vms.ip)) : " -NoNewline
              Write-host "NOK" -foreground red}

   if ($vms.gateway -eq $gatewayget.scriptoutput){Write-host  "Gateway ($($vms.gateway)): " -NoNewline
              write-host "OK" -foreground green}

        else {Write-host  "Gateway ($($vms.gateway)): " -NoNewline
              Write-host "NOK" -foreground red}}
```

I know the problem is related to the variable $gatewayget but I can't find it out.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Say the IP for one of your VMs is `10.1.1.7`. Is your Invoke-VMScript meant be running the results of `Get-Variable -Name "10.1.1.7" | select -ExpandProperty Value`? Maybe sensible if that result is a scriptblock, but you have not posted the piece of code where that scriptblock variable is set?

Comment: My main problem is that the result is a scriptoutput. If I set my "invoke-vmscript..." as "$gatewayget", the result will be a scriptoutput with the gateway adress. But $gatewayget.defaultipgateway won't work. I'm sorry my english is not really good !